# Is it allowed to use two generic T types (like T and TSource) in C# methods?

Tags: c#, generics

Is it allowed to use two generic T types (like T and TSource) in C# methods?

```
public T GetResutls<T>(TSource sourceClass, string jsonString) where TSource : class
```

Comment: Yes, but you need to include `TSource` in `GetResults<TSource, T>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you have to write both types between the angle brackets:

```
    public TResult GetResults<TResult, TSource>(TSource source)
    {
       // TODO: Implement your code here
    }
```

Comment: Great, following the [docs' naming guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters#type-parameter-naming-guidelines) as well :+1: